# Subclassing and overriding methods

Tags: java

I have class `A` and class `B` which extends `A`.

```
class A {

    public void play(){
      System.out.println("A"):
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void play(){
      System.out.println("B"):
    }
}
```

Lets say I have something like that:

```
 A myObj = new B();
 ((A)myObj).play;
```

This is still show `B` in the system out. Shouldn't it show `A` since I upcasted it and I executed play.  How can I call the super play given that my object is of type `B`?

Comment: Nope. That's not how Java works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting a reference does not change the underling object.

`myObj` is a variable that stores a reference to an `A` object. In your code, that object is a `B`.

When you cast `myObjt` to a `B` you're [narrowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) the reference to a subclass so that you can invoke one of its methods. This does nothing to the `B` object.

Comment: So is there a way I can the super method? If not I guessI  have to put some logic in the subclass play to call the higher one

Comment: @Snake You can't from the calling code. You can do it within the `B` methods with the `super` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The cast is irrelevant.  The whole point of polymorphism is that the version of the method that gets called depends on the *class of the object* (that is, what it was created as), and not on the *type of the referring expression* (that is, what it was declared as or cast to).

Answer (score 0):

`((A)myObj) is not doing nothing here`, no point casting integer to integer.

Also typecasting doesnt change object reference.